# What is the technical name for temporary construction fences?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

My structural engineering friend and I passed a construction site years ago, and he called those temporary fences a technical name. Now I ask him the technical name he said those years and he doesn't even remember the moment, understandably, and is not sure there is even a technical name to begin with. I googled "what is the fence built around ongoing projects called" and 'temporary fencing" came up.

This is my final straw to chalk it up to a distorted memory or finally learn that elusive name (every few months I remember that moment and still don't remember the name). So is there any technical name for temporary construction fences just as we have aggregates for sand, gravel, etc? If there is, please for the love of sanity, what is it?

Comment: Add a picture for extra question-quality-points ;D

Comment: hahaha I dont know if you have time to read a thousand words ;)

Comment: Are you sure it was a technical term?  In the UK, if it's the sort that's a wire mesh on a tubular frame that slots into heavy blocks it's often called 'Heras fencing', but that's not a technical term, it's a trade name - so it's like lots of vacuum cleaners get called a 'hoover'.  But this all probably applies only in the UK.

Comment: @achrn yeah I think so. Thanks for the Heras info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this “site hoarding” (google images preview below - is this what you’re thinking of?)

[image]

Comment: I think it might be site hoarding, but its possible he just called it hoarding because I remember it as one word. Thank you very much Jonathan :) Sorry cant cast votes for now but I'll just accept the answer

Comment: Hoarding is a more general term that would also include billboards etc. that are neither temporary nor around a construction site - but it may well be the word he used :)

Comment: Is "hoarding" in this context a UK word? I've never heard it in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Those are referred to as barricading or hoardings they are primarily meant for vision obstruction and to maintain/act as wind barriers to trap dust emissions.

Comment: There are also a health & safety & security purposes for hoardings, to prevent unauthorized people from accessing construction sites.

Answer (score 0):

It is called Tapume.  It is an English term but more often used in Brazilian Portuguese.